# Dividing the results of multiple queries in Azure KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-sdk-for-java

I have a series of KQL queries (Query1, Query2, Query3, Query4) and I'm looking to perform a calculation on their results. Specifically, I want to divide the result of (Query1 + Query2) by (Query3 + Query4).

Here's the pseudo-code of what I'm trying to achieve:

**Result = (Query1 + Query2) / (Query3 + Query4)**

Is there a way to accomplish this directly within Azure KQL?

I've tried experimenting with different approaches, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you share the same data and query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to achieve that using `toscalar()`:

```
let result1 = toscalar(...query1...);
let result2 = toscalar(...query2...);
let result3 = toscalar(...query3...);
let result4 = toscalar(...query4...);
print result = (result1 + result2) / (result3 + result4)
```